# Date Virtual field - cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, date, datetime, cakephp-2.0

Small logical problem. I'm learning CakePHP 2.0 and i've used virtual fields before but this time i want to format the `DATETIME` fields.

As output, I get `YYYY-MM-DD` (numeric like 2010-10-31) but I want the output to be just `September, 2005`

what logic should i apply to get this in a virtual field, or if there's a better approach pls give me a direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your are using Mysql you can use DATE_FORMAT function.

Add a virtual field to your Model file  like this:

```
class Yourmodel extends AppModel {

     var $virtualFields = array(
                'formateddate' => 'DATE_FORMAT(Yourmodel.mysqldate,"%d/%m/%Y")');

.
.
.
}
```

Change the format string to your needs.